# Narrow TypeScript type via external function?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write an external function to narrow the type of objects with TypeScript, however as soon as I pull the logic out TypeScript seems to lose the thread. I've got the following code:

```
if (element instanceof HTMLInputElement && element.checked) {
  // do something
}
```

However, I'd like to pull the first check out and send us a notification that something is off:

```
function assertType(element, expectedType) {
  if (element instanceof expectedType) { return true; }

  notify(`element ${element} wasn't expected type ${expectedType}`);

  return false;
}

if (assertType(element, HTMLInputElement) && element.checked) {
  // do something
}
```

TypeScript is happy with the first, but the second it complains about:

```
error TS2339: Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.
```

Even if I reduce it to the bare minimum it still fails:

```
function assertType(element, expectedType) {
  return element instanceof expectedType;
}
```

Is there a way I can write the `assertType` function so that TypeScript is able to narrow the type? I'm trying to avoid having a type cast to ensure that the types are in line with the underlying html, but I guess I could use that in a pinch. Maybe even something like:

```
if (assertType(element, HTMLInputElement) && (element as HTMLInputElement).checked) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of [user-defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)?

Comment: I had seen those, however unless I'm missing something it looks like they don't support arbitrary types. Is there a way to do it without needing a separate helper function for every type that I want to be able to assert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a job for [user-defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards), along with [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) so that it can apply to any type.  Here's one way to make your `assertType` function:

```
function assertType<T>(element: any, expectedType: new(...args: any[])=>T): element is T {
  return element instanceof expectedType;
}
```

The idea is that `expectedType` should be a constructor for some generic type `T`, and it will return whether or not `element is T`.  Let's see if it works, type system wise:

```
declare const element: Element;

if (assertType(element, HTMLInputElement) && (element.checked)) {
  // do something
}
```

No errors.  Hope that helps.  Good luck!

---

#### UPDATE

> What if you want to make it even more generic and allow `expectedType` to be either a constructor to match with `instanceof` or a string to match with `typeof`?

That seems a bit much to want one function to do, but if I were to try I'd probably use [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) and [lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types), like this:

```
type TypeofMapping = {
  string: string,
  number: number,
  boolean: boolean,
  symbol: symbol,
  undefined: undefined,
  object: object,
  function: Function
}

function assertType<T>(element: any, expectedType: new (...args: any[]) => T): element is T;
function assertType<K extends keyof TypeofMapping>(element: any, expectedType: K): element is TypeofMapping[K];
function assertType(element: any, expectedType: new (...args: any[]) => any | keyof TypeofMapping): boolean {
  return (typeof expectedType === "string") ? typeof element === expectedType : element instanceof expectedType;
}
```

The point is to have the code pick one of the two overloads.  The first one is as before, but the second one constrains the `expectedType` to one of the strings that the runtime `typeof` operator returns, and maps that string to the type via `TypeofMapping`.  Let's try it again:

```
declare const element: Element;

if (assertType(element, HTMLInputElement) && (element.checked)) {
  // do something
}

declare const otherThing: string | number;
if (assertType(otherThing, "string") && otherThing.charAt(0) === 'a') {
  // do something else
}
```

Also seems to work (haven't tested at runtime though).  Still I'd shy away from that kind of split-personality function myself.  Up to you.  Good luck again!

Comment: Actually, a quick followup. What if you want to make it even more generic and allow `expectedType` to be either a constructor to match with `instanceof` or a string to match with `typeof`? I guess I might make two functions for it, but curious what that would look like in one.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Looks like you're right about the complexity of it. I'll probably go with 2 functions.